# DirectX 9 "Loading textures" progress bar

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, directx-9

It doesn't need to look like a progress bar.
All I need it to say is "Loading images..." while the texture is loading, then saying "Done" when it's done loading.

I have no idea, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something like this in a DirectX application I was working on.

The idea behind it is to use the `D3DXSPRITE` interface to draw text to the screen. Begin drawing the scene with the Direct3D device, begin drawing with the sprite, call the sprite's `DrawText` function, and then end the sprite and the device scene.

**NOTE:** This requires that your Direct3D device and sprite be initialized *before* you start loading textures.

The way I did it was that I had a stack of `Dialog/Popup` objects that I drew to the screen every time my `redraw` function was called, so before I loaded the textures, I added a `Dialog` with the loading message, redrew the screen, then started loading, and then replaced/modified the dialog with the "Done!" message, and redrew again.

Hope it helps!